# Do all Android classes extend Activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm going through some Android development tutorials, and I notice that some classes extend Activity, and others extend ListActivity for example.

By default, does a newly created class implicitly extend Activity or do you need to explicitly extend it?

Also, when a class extends ListActivity, why do you not have to extend Activity? Or does ListActivity already extend Activity?

I read a few similar questions but it wasn't quite clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "default", all Android Activities extend `Activity`.

> By default, does a newly created class implicitly extend Activity or do you need to explicitly extend it?

You have to explicitly state that it should extend `Activity` if it does not already and if you plan to use it as an Activity. Kindly note that you there are times you wouldn't do it. For example, when you have a class for your objects or whatnot, then you don't need to extend Activity any longer.

> Also, when a class extends ListActivity, why do you not have to extend Activity? Or does ListActivity already extend Activity?

`ListActivity`, `AppCompatActivity`, and any other class that ends in `-Activity` are "children of the `Activity` class. So by extension, extending by these "children" would already extend from the parent `Activity` class and you'll no longer need to do something like `YourActivity extends ListActivity, Activity`. I think Android Studio will give you an error if you do.

The difference between an `Activity` and a `ListAcivity` is that a ListActivity will require you to override several methods because it is expecting a ListView in its content.

Answer (score 2):

Android is written in Java, and like all java classes, every class inherits from the `Object` class.

> Does a newly created class implicitly extend Activity or do you need to explicitly extend it?

You need to extend it.

> Does ListActivity already extend Activity?

Yes.

You can see class hierarchy for ListActivity [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html).

Answer (score 1):

Newly created classes do not extend anything. ListActivity is a subclass of Activity so all of the functionality Activity has, ListActivity inherits. In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#inhmethods) for ListActivity you can see that it is a subclass of Activity.

Answer (score 1):

In Android, All the classes are not extended by Activity.

Only the screens which render the UI are extended by Activity. So, if you want to create a UI screen then you have to explicitly extend it with Activity class and override the callback methods.

ListActivity is subclass of Activity which is only used when you have only a ListView in the your layout.It has some specific listview related methods.

Similarly, if you wanna create a fragment, your class will extend the Fragment Class and override its methods. Similarly for Service, BroadcastReceiver etc.